# GCC/Clang equivalent to Intel ICC #pragma forceinline recursive

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Does clang/gcc has a way to do what Intel icc does with `#pragma forceinline recursive` or anything close to that?

> ```
> #pragma forceinline [recursive]
> ```
>
> Specifies inlining of all calls in a statement.
>
> The `forceinline` pragma indicates that the calls in question should be inlined whenever the compiler is capable of doing so.
>
> `recursive` indicates that the pragma applies to all of the calls that are called by these calls, recursively, down the call chain
>
> These are statement-specific inlining pragmas. Each can be placed before a C/C++ statement, and will then apply to all of the calls within a statement and all calls within statements nested within that statement.

(https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524498)

I would prefer not to use `__attribute__((always_inline))` since it applies to functions. And the function in my case is not exactly small. And I would like to leave it for the compiler to determine when to inline it in most cases. Besides, though this attribute is very strong, it still is not "**always**". Changing global options such as inline depth and size limit are also not ideal.

However, in some particular cases, I know for fact that inlining the function can has a big impact on performance (in my case, by a factor of 2). Intel's `#pragma inline/forceinline [recursive]` applies to individual statement and has exactly the effect that I want. Does GCC or clang has any thing similar that can effect only a particular call site of a function?

Comment: AFAIK there's no such a thing in gcc. If you control that function, you may put its body into an `__attribute__((always_inline))` function, and then provide the "regular" version which is just a wrapper around the always_inline version. For the `recursive` thing, you may play try to do similar tricks with the `flatten` attribute.

Comment: The flatten attribute is probably the closest if you factor that call site out to an always inline function.

Comment: Thanks. flatten seems useful. And thanks for editing the question to clarify the intel pragma @MatteoItalia

Comment: @MatteoItalia This should be an answer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, please post your comment as an answer so we can get this question out of the unanswered column.